# How to fetch data from DB in android every 2 mins?

Tags: android, database

I developed a simple android application and was able to post and get information from database through http request and doing this with AsyncTask. My question is if i want to poll information from the db every 5 mins or check if any new data has been posted to the db how i could this be done in android?

Answer (score 0):

Use **CountDownTimer**
check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) out

300000ms = 5 min

```
 CountDownTimer chkDb=   new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
             //code for db check 
             chkDb.start();//start again after 5 min
         }
      }.start();
```

**OR**

Use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

```
private TimerTask mTimerTask;
private Timer t = new Timer();

public void doTimerTask() {

        mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        callYourMethodHere();
                        Log.i("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
        t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 1000); //

    }

    public void stopTask() {

        if (mTimerTask != null) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "timer canceled");
            mTimerTask.cancel();
        }

    }


task -- This is the task to be scheduled.

delay -- This is the delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.

period -- This is the time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
```

Comment: will this work with asyncTask. I use asyncTask when sending an http get request and read async should be used when performing short operations

Comment: when u say callYourMethodHere thats where i execute my http get request?

Comment: yes make another method doing all http request or db checks and call that method in countdowntimer or timertask

Comment: Thanks and i aslo see stopTask method, when is it called?

Comment: whenever you want to interrupt the timer in between like cancelling the timer but looks like in your case its of no use.

Comment: your right in my case would not be needed. Thanks for responses and patience would take a look and try it out

Comment: @Madur so basically the example you posted it will run every 1 sec with 0.5sec delay

Comment: added more desc in answer

Comment: added what task, delay period means check last line in code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that polling the DB every 5 min is a nice solution. It's a waste of resources.

Instead of that, consider using some mechanism that informs you when something in the DB has change so your UI can refresh properly.

For example, in some projects I have used [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to send an event when a new item has been inserted in the DB. My fragments subscribe to a default bus so they are aware when something has change.

Pros: Performance. The app only works when it has to

Cons: Well, not much really. The easy solution is to say: "OK, something has change. Let's throw all the current info shown in UI and make a new query to DB!". BUT the **nice** solution is to say: "OK, something has change. What has change and how can I add that new info to UI?"

But that depends on the app context ;)

Comment: interesting never used otto before will take a look at it. Do you have tutorials or sample of how to implement otto

Comment: Actually is quite simple. You can check [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html) for some info but as soon as you start using it you will learn fast